# Reference to Function syntax - with and without &

Tags: c++

What's the difference between

```
typedef void (&FunctionTypeR)();
```

vs

```
typedef void (FunctionType)();
```

Is the second also a reference to function?  Is `FunctionTypeR` equivalent to `FunctionType&` when used as the type of an argument?

For

```
void foo(FunctionType bar)
```

Does the runtime makes a copy of the argument bar (a function) when foo is invoked?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference is that you **cannot** create objects of function type, but you can create of objects of function *pointer* type, and function *reference* type.

That means if you've a function, say `f()` as:

```
 void f(){}
```

then here is what you can do, and what you cannot do:

```
FunctionType  fun1 = f; //error - cannot create object of function type
FunctionType *fun2 = f; //ok 
FunctionTypeR fun3 = f; //ok
```

Test code:

```
typedef void (&FunctionTypeR)();
typedef void FunctionType();

void f(){}

int main() {
        FunctionType  fun1 = f; //error - cannot create object of function type
        FunctionType *fun2 = f; //ok 
        FunctionTypeR fun3 = f; //ok
        return 0;
}
```

Now see the compilation error (and warnings):

```
 prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
 prog.cpp:7: error: function ‘void fun1()’ is initialized like a variable
 prog.cpp:8: warning: unused variable ‘fun2’
 prog.cpp:9: warning: unused variable ‘fun3’
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/hpTEv

---

However, if you use `FunctionType` (which is a function type) in a function parameter list as:

```
void foo(FunctionType bar);
```

then it's equivalent to

```
void foo(FunctionType * bar);
```

That means, no matter what you write, you can call the function using `bar` as:

```
   bar();  //ok
 (*bar)(); //ok
```

That is, you can write this:

```
void h(FunctionType fun) { fun(); }
void g(FunctionType fun) { (*fun)(); }
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/kwUE9

This is due to *function type to function pointer type* adjustment; that is, the *function type* is **adjusted** to become a *pointer to function type*:

```
Function type     |  Function pointer type (adjusted type)
   void ()        |     void (*)()
   void (int)     |     void (*)(int)
   int  (int,int) |     int  (*)(int,int)
   ....           |      ... so on
```

The C++03 Standard says in §13.1/3,

> Parameter declarations that differ only in that one is a function type and the other is a pointer to the same function type are **equivalent**. **That is, the function type is adjusted to become a pointer to function type (8.3.5)**.

```
[Example:
    void h(int());
    void h(int (*)()); // redeclaration of h(int())
    void h(int x()) { } // definition of h(int())
    void h(int (*x)()) { } // ill-formed: redefinition of h(int())
]
```

And if you use `` `FunctionTypeR `` (which is a function *reference* type) as:

```
void foo(FunctionTypeR bar);
```

then it's equivalent to:

```
void foo(FunctionType * & bar);
```

And,

```
void h(FunctionTypeR fun) { fun(); }
void g(FunctionTypeR fun) { (*fun)(); }
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/SmtQv

---

## Interesting part...

You can use FunctionType to *declare* a function (but not to define it).

For example,

```
struct A
{
   //member function declaration. 
    FunctionType f; //equivalent to : void f();
};

void A::f() //definition
{
  std::cout << "haha" << std::endl;
}

//forward declaration
FunctionType h; //equivalent to : void h();

int main() {
        A a;
        a.f(); //call member function
        h();   //call non-member function
}

void h() //definition goes below main()
{
   std::cout <<"hmmm.." << std::endl;
}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/W4ED2

Comment: Does it mean void foo(FunctionType bar) is actually foo(FunctionType& bar)? which is equivalent to foo(FunctionTypeR bar)?

Comment: void 'foo(FunctionType bar)' is not an error. it compiles and runs.  The error is 'FunctionType fun1 = f';

Comment: Candy: I updated my answer. There was some confusion my mind as well. I clarified it now.

Comment: I'd say that the function type isn't entirely useless, because you can happily use it as a template parameter type, as is done by `std::function`. You can't have instances of that type, that's true, but the type itself is still useful.

Comment: @Kerrek: I didn't say function type is *entirely* useless.

Comment: @Kerrek: Although, I didn't say that `function type is entirely useless`, I changed the wordings of my answer. I hope it's better now.

Comment: @Nawaz What confuses me is (in MSVC) typeid(FunctionType) == typeid(FunctionTypeR) == "void __cdecl()", while typeid(FunctionTypeP) == "void (__cdecl*)()".  If your theory is correct, I'd expect typeid(FunctionType) == "void (__cdecl*)()"?

Comment: @Candy: No, I did NOT say that `FunctionType` and `FunctionType*` are same. They're of different type. But in function parameter list, they're *equivalent*.

Comment: @Candy: I quoted the relevant text from the C++ Standard which talks about that they're equivalent when they appear in function parameter list.

Comment: There are a couple of subtle errors in this answer. For example, `FunctionType f` is correct, and it declares a function with the appropriate signature, what is not correct is trying to initialize it from a different function, so the problem is with the `= f` part, just as you cannot do: `void function() = f;`, which makes the *interesting part* less surprising or interesting. There is no such thing as *the equivalence property* (as a noun), what you are talking about is commonly known as *decay* (a function identifier decays into a pointer, as an array also decays to a pointer)

Comment: @Nawaz: Why do we need FunctionType at all when the other 2 seems to supersede it in every way?

Comment: @ZachSaw: You want to have pointer to function type, without having first the function type itself? Does it even make sense? :|