# Function pointers as parameters in C++?

Tags: c++

I am confused by the form of parameters for function pointers. The following two:

```
int fun(int (*g)())
{
    cout << g() << endl;
}

int fun(int g())
{
    cout << g() << endl;
}
```

Both these two definitions work well. But as you have noticed, there are some differences in the prototypes of these two functions:

- the first one takes parameter `int (*g)()`,
- while the second takes parameter `int g()`.

My question is are there any difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case, the function type adjusts to become *pointer-to-function-type*, which makes the both function identical.

```
int fun(int (*g)()); 
int fun(int g()); //same as above, after type adjustment
```

The C++03 Standard says in §13.1/3,

> Parameter declarations that differ only in that one is a function type and the other is a pointer to the same function type are **equivalent**. **That is, the function type is adjusted to become a pointer to function type (8.3.5)**.

```
[Example:
    void h(int());
    void h(int (*)());  // redeclaration of h(int())
    void h(int x()) { } // definition of h(int())
    void h(int (*x)()) { } // ill-formed: redefinition of h(int())
]
```

---

It's same as with array to pointer adjustement, with which we're more familiar:

```
int fun(int *a); 
int fun(int a[]);   //same as above, after type adjustment
int fun(int a[10]); //same as above, after type adjustment
```

All are same!

You can a detail answer by me here:

- [Reference to Function syntax - with and without &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321993/reference-to-function-syntax-with-and-without/7322098#7322098)

Comment: Can you explain why C++ decays int g() to pointer-to-function-type, the first one is pointer-to-function-type, but the second one is different from the first one, as you see, one more * symbol. For the array example it is easy to understand.

Comment: @Nawaz: There are two distinct rules in play here.  An expression of function type is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function in most contexts (including an ordinary function call like `foo()`); this conversion is commonly called *decay*.  A parameter declared to be of function type is *adjusted* to become pointer-to-function parameter.  The two rules are related, but in principle the language could have one rule but not the other.  Likewise for array-to-pointer decay and array-to-pointer parameter adjustment.

Comment: @cheng: For array, why is it easy to understand? Because you've seen this more frequently? Also, function type to pointer to function type conversion is allowed by the C++ Standard, in such situation. That is why,it decays.

Comment: @cheng: Read the updated answer, with quotation from the Standard.

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually have a parameter of function type.  A function parameter declared as if it were of type "function returning T" is *adjusted* to be of type "pointer to function returning T.  So your two definitions are effectively identical.  (C has the same rule.)

A similar rule applies to array parameter declarations.  For example this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

really means this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

Comment: For the example you provided I can understand because "char *argv[]" and "char **argv" are indeed identical. But for int (*g)() and int g() how could they be the same.

Comment: Further more, if the two are identical, then the following definitions are also identical? typedef int (*funP) (void);
typedef int funP2 (void);

Comment: @user508305: They're identical because a function parameter declaration is adjusted at compile time to a pointer-to-function declaration.  It's similar to the adjustment rule that makes `char *argv[]` and `char **argv` equivalent (but *only* as a parameter declaration).

Comment: @user508305: No, those two typedefs are not identical.  One makes `funP` a pointer type, the other makes it a function type.  The adjustment rule applies *only* to parameter declarations, not to `typedef`s.

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted.  I welcome constructive criticism.  If you think I'm mistaken, please read the C and C++ standard references I cited in comments on Foo Bah's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers (e.g. MSVC, g++) accept the second form as a shorthand for the first.  Technically speaking you should always use the first form.

Comment: They accept it because the language requires them to do so.  See 8.3.5p3 ([dcl.fct]) in the C++ 2003 standard.

Comment: @Keith Is there an equivalent note in the C standard?

Comment: Yes, [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.7.5.3p7 and p8.