# Difference between two ways of using default constructor

Tags: c++

What is the difference between defining an object of class "Person" by using its default constructor following two different ways:

Method 1:

```
Person person = Person();
```

Method 2:

```
Person person();
```

When I initialized some variables inside the default constructor and tried to access those variables or set those variables by get/set methods in the main routine, I got compilation error in Method 2, but Method 1 works.

Thanks.

Comment: "I got compilation"? what does that even mean? BTW the second one is not invoking the default consturctor, it's a function declaration.

Comment: Your question is based on the false assumption that both of those use the default constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [About Pointers To Functions in function declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327505/about-pointers-to-functions-in-function-declarations)

Comment: y'all folks here, this does not deserve two upvotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You're awfully dupe-happy nowadays. That's obviously not a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Person person = Person();
```

This declares a `Person` object called `person`. It initialises this object with a temporary object created by `Person()`. That means it'll invoke the copy/move constructor of `Person` (which will probably be elided).

```
Person person();
```

This declares a *function* called `person` that returns a `Person` object. This is not a declaration of an object.

You most likely want this instead:

```
Person person;
```

This declares a `Person` object called `person` which is default constructed.

You may want to use the new "uniform" initialisation syntax introduced in C++11, which avoids the ambiguities between variable and function declarations:

```
Person person{};
```

And finally, if you're [AAA](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)-minded, you may want to use the style proposed by Herb Sutter:

```
auto person = Person{};
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that a compiler that doesn't elide that copy/move is probably worthless these days.

Comment: @chris You know when you're thinking faster than your writing and end up missing something out? That happened.

Comment: Maybe mention `Person person{}`?

Comment: @Deduplicator or `auto person = Person{};` ;-) Just kidding, the [author of this answer is on record](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/dont-use-auto-unless-you-mean-it.html) for not liking it.

Comment: @TemplateRex Added it anyway. ;)