# invalid user-defined conversion

Tags: c++

please have a look at this program and the error it is generating:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    class A
    {
    public:

        virtual void f(){}
        int i;
    };

    class B : public A
    {
    public:
        B(int i_){i = i_;} //needed
        B(){}              //needed
        void f(){}
    };

    int main()
    {

        //these two lines are fixed(needed)
        B b;
        A & a = b;

        //Assignment 1 works
        B b1(2);
        b = b1;

        //But Assignment 2  doesn't works
        B b2();
        b = b2; // <-- error
    }
```

upon compilation, I get the following error:

```
$ g++ inher2.cpp 
inher2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
inher2.cpp:32:10: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘B()’ to ‘const B&’ [-fpermissive]
inher2.cpp:14:6: note: candidate is: B::B(int) <near match>
inher2.cpp:14:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘B()’ to ‘int’
inher2.cpp:32:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘B (*)()’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
inher2.cpp:14:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘B::B(int)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Can you help me find the problem? thank you

Comment: Where's that most vexing parse question when you need it?

Comment: @chris First I thought you are joking, until I saw the answers :) vexing!... :) thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "B b2();" is the '***vexing parse***' problem of C++ ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) - the '***most vexing parse***' takes the ambiguous syntax further).

It looks to the C++ compiler that you are declaring a function (a pre-declaration).

Check it out:

```
int foo(); //A function named 'foo' that takes zero parameters and returns an int.

B b2(); //A function named 'b2' that takes zero parameters and returns a 'B'.
```

When you later do:

```
b = b2;
```

It looks like you are trying to assign a function (**b2**) to a variable (**b**).
To call a constructor with zero parameters, call it without the parentheses and you'll be fine:

```
B b2;
```

For more information, see:

- [Understanding 'most vexing parse' - why allow ambiguous syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535388/understanding-most-vexing-parse-why-allow-ambiguous-syntax)
- [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: That is not "most" vexing parse. It is just vexing parse!

Comment: @Nawaz what do you mean :) the title of his link to wikipedia says it is "Most" vexing!

Comment: Most vexing is the format "***B b2(B())***". Vexing is the format "***B b2();***". The Wikipedia article shows an explanation of the former.

Answer (score 2):

```
B b2();
```

It is a function declaration, **not** a variable declaration!

The function name is `b2` which takes no argument, and returns object of type `B`.

Search for *vexing parse* in C++.